# django template date filter format string question

Tags: python, django

I have a datetime value that is available in a django template.

I am trying to format the date as "d-mmm"

so for example dates are formated as:

- 5-Mar
- 10-Mar
- 4-Apr

etc.

I have tried different combinations - NOTHING works so far?. I hope I dont have to write a custom filter just to format a date ?

**[Edit]**

I tried the 'obvious' format string like: 'j-M', 'j-N', (even 'j-mmm' and 'd-mmm')

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried `{{ some_date|date:"j-M" }}`?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Yes, that gives dates like "5-March", "4-April" etc, which is NOT what I want. I want 3 letter abbreviations of the month names

Comment: Huh?  `|date:"j-F"` gives you things like "5-March".  `|date:"j-M"` should give you the three-letter abbreviated version.  At least, that's how it's documented from Django 1.0 onward to the current development version.  What version of Django do you have?

Comment: @skyeagle "j-M" works perfectly for me. It's really strange that it doesn't for you.

Comment: @chefsmart: Eeek, don't know what happened there (must have forgotten to refresh my browser after the change). It does work - my bad. Time foranother cup of coffee I think ...